# How to debug odoo in docker?

Tags: docker, debugging, visual-studio-code, odoo

I am not able to debug odoo in docker container.

I am using Visual Studio Code and I have the following launch.json configuration.

```
{
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
       {
           "name": "Odoo 12",
           "type": "python",
           "request": "launch",
           "stopOnEntry": false,
           "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
           "program": "/usr/bin/odoo",
           "args": [
             "--config=/etc/odoo/odoo.conf"
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

Everytime I start a debugger, this error occurs:

```
Exception in thread odoo.service.httpd:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 410, in http_thread
    self.httpd = ThreadedWSGIServerReloadable(self.interface, self.port, app)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 136, in __init__
    handler=RequestHandler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 476, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 440, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 151, in server_bind
    super(ThreadedWSGIServerReloadable, self).server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 454, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my debug configuration?

Thanks!!

**UPDATE**

Perhaps some more information is necessary. 
I start the odoo-server with a docker-compose file and then with VSCode I remotely attach to that odoo-server. 
Restarting the server with the odoo-bin command works fine with VSCode terminal.

I have two docker containers running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
4ac4a4c8481f        odoo:12.0           "/entrypoint.sh odoo…"   7 days ago          Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:8069->8069/tcp, 8071/tcp   odoo-docker_web_1
5910cce38985        postgres:10         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 days ago          Up 4 minutes        5432/tcp                           odoo-docker_db_1
```

And only odoo server is running on 8069:

```
odoo@4ac4a4c8481f:/mnt/extra-addons$ lsof -i :8069
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python3   1 odoo    7u  IPv4  44986      0t0  TCP *:8069 (LISTEN)
```

So probably I am wrong using "launch" request type, because it tries to restart the server. 
I have also tested this configuration:

```
{
   "name": "Odoo 12 Attach",
   "type": "python",
   "request": "attach",
   "port": 8069,
   "host": "localhost",           
 },
```

but then the debugger is terminating immediately without error message.

Comment: The error indicates that the port is already in use. are you running the same service twice?

Comment: No, it is just odoo running on that port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to understand how `remote debugging` works for all python services or apps which based on it such as Odoo, Flask, Django, Web2py or whatever. you have to understand three different concepts the docker container, the debugger, the python app server (in our case it's Odoo). so in many cases, when running Odoo from docker it is like the following image:
[image]

and what you really need to be able to debug would be like the following image:
[image]

please note the difference:

- without debugging you have two ports, one internal the other is external which will pass http requests from the browser to Odoo & vice versa. however after debugging you have 4 ports, 2 of them for the http request & the other 2 for debugging information (which is based on json in our case) from Vscode to `debugpy` & vice versa (you could also use 2 ports by the way).
- without debugging your entrypoint would be whats defined in the `Dockerfile`. with debugging, you modify the entrypoint to be `debugpy`. which will be responsible for running Odoo

czuniga, approach is really good & it is almost the same as following:

works with **vscode 1.45.0** & later. for reference files https://gist.github.com/kerbrose/e646aaf9daece42b46091e2ca0eb55d0

1- Edit your `docker.dev` file & insert `RUN pip3 install -U debugpy`. this will install a python package `debugpy` instead of the deprecated one `ptvsd` because your vscode (local) will be communicating to `debugpy` (remote) server of your docker image using it.

2- Start your containers. however you will be starting the python package that you just installed `debugpy`. it could be as next command from your shell.

```sh
docker-compose run --rm -p 8888:3001 -p 8879:8069 {DOCKER IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST]} /usr/bin/python3 -m debugpy --listen 0.0.0.0:3001 /usr/bin/odoo --db_user=odoo --db_host=db --db_password=odoo
```

3- Prepare your launcher file as following. please note that `port` will be related to odoo server. `debugServer` will be the port for the debug server

```json
{
    "name": "Odoo: Attach",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 8879,
    "debugServer": 8888,
    "host": "localhost",
    "pathMappings": [
        {
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/mnt/extra-addons",
        }
    ],
    "logToFile": true
```

Comment: where do I find docker.dev file?

Comment: well docker.dev is the same as the docker configuration with additional development setting. so you may not have it. it is according your environment. you probably have one docker file.

Comment: I solved it by installing debugpy from command in docker-compose.yml, so I don't need docker.dev file.

Answer (score 4):

I made it work following the next steps:

1. Start containers with `docker-compose up` or `docker run`
2. Access your odoo container with root permissions using 
   `docker exec -it -u 0 "container name" /bin/bash`
3. Install ptvsd `pip3 install ptvsd`
4. Update odoo `addons/__init__.py` file to enable ptvsd attachement,locate file in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/__init__.py` and add the following code at the end of the file:

```
import ptvsd
ptvsd.enable_attach(address=('0.0.0.0', 3000))

ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
```

5. Exit container and restart using `docker-compose restart` or `docker restart "container name"`
6. Execute `docker inspect "container name"` and copy the `IPAddress` under the `Networks` section
7. Open visual studio and create the `launch.json`, paste the container ip under the `host` field and the `port` that was specified on the ptvsd attach method, ex. In my case the ip was 172.27.0.3

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 3000,
            "host": "172.27.0.3",
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

8. Click on start Debugging and you should be able to see odoo logs on the **Debug console**

[image]

Note: Be sure to expose port 3000 on container

Comment: It is working for me, if I add "debugServer": 3000 inside launch.json. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes when restarting docker-compose odoo is left shutdown. Do you know what I can do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Check running containers and also locally running odoo instances somethings definitely running on that port

> lsof -i :8069 >> Try running it with the port number you are using in place of 8069
>
> docker ps >> To see all running containers further you can use pycham to run debug in container

[see also] (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/)

Comment: An odoo instance is running on that port 8069. I have only two docker container running - that is odoo- and postgreSQL-container.